# Node.js API returns JSON in terminal but not in browser

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, monodevelop

Having a strange problem. Been searching for answers but nothing turns up. I'm doing a node api tutorial and it returns JSON from my mongoDB database in my terminal when I perform any GET request but in my browser or postman I get nothing back, only in the terminal do I get any response. When I try a POST in  postman it says it can't connect to the backend.

here is my code :

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var database = require('./database');


// Generic find methods (GET)

function findAllResources(resourceName, req, res) {
  database.find('OrderBase', resourceName, {}, function (err, resources) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  res.end(JSON.stringify(resources));
  });
};

var findResourceById = function (resourceName, id, req, res) {
  database.find('OrderBase', resourceName, {'_id': id}, function (err, resource) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  res.end(JSON.stringify(resource));
  });
};

// Product methods

var findAllProducts = function (req, res) {
  findAllResources('Products', req, res);
};

var findProductById = function (id, req, res) {
  findResourceById('Products', id, req, res);
};

// Generic insert/update methods (POST, PUT)

var insertResource = function (resourceName, resource, req, res) {
  database.insert('OrderBase', resourceName, resource, function (err, resource) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  res.end(JSON.stringify(resource));
  });
};

// Product methods

var insertProduct = function (product, req, res) {
  insertResource('OrderBase', 'Product', product, function (err, result) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
  });
};


var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  // Break down the incoming URL into its components
  var parsedURL = url.parse(req.url, true);

  // determine a response based on the URL
  switch (parsedURL.pathname) {
    case '/api/products':
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
      // Find and return the product with the given id
      if (parsedURL.query.id) {
        findProductById(id, req, res)
      }
      // There is no id specified, return all products
      else {
        findAllProducts(req, res);
      }
    }
    else if (req.method === 'POST') {

      //Extract the data stored in the POST body
      var body = '';
      req.on('data', function (dataChunk) {
        body += dataChunk;
      });
      req.on('end', function () {
        // Done pulling data from the POST body.
        // Turn it into JSON and proceed to store it in the database.
        var postJSON = JSON.parse(body);
        insertProduct(postJSON, req, res);
      });
    }
    break;
    default:
    res.end('You shall not pass!');
  }
});
server.listen(8080);

console.log('Up and running, ready for action!');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several callbacks with `err` as first argument but you are not treating any potential error. It means if something is going wrong, you are not catching it and returning an error. I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but as a practice (not even "best", but general practice) instead of doing this

```
function (err, resource) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  res.end(JSON.stringify(resource));
  }
```

do this

```
function (err, resource) {
  if(err){
    // do something to warn the client and stop here
  }
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  res.end(JSON.stringify(resource));
  }
```

Try that, see if you are actually running into errors before trying to output an answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback

The response end method not send data to response socket. Maybe you change it

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
res.end(JSON.stringify(resource));

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
res.write(JSON.stringify(resource));
res.end();
```

if you want socket to close to do something, you can into callback to end.

```
res.end(#logHandle());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var assert = require('assert');


var connect = function  (databaseName, callback) {
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/' + databaseName;

MongoClient.connect(url, function  (error, database) {
    assert.equal(null, error);

    console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB instance!");

    callback(database);
})
};


exports.find = function  (databaseName, collectioName, query, callback) {
connect(databaseName, function  (database) {
    var collection = database.collection(collectioName);

    collection.find(query).toArray(
        function  (err, documents) {
            assert.equal(err, null);

            console.log('MongoDB returned the following documents:');
            console.dir(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(documents)));
            //console.dir(documents);
            callback(null, documents);
        }
    )

    database.close();
})
};
```

I think we are going through the same tutorial, this is my solution of 'database.js', works for me.